# Как изменить сдвигание блока при активном состоянии?

Tags: css

Привет! 
Есть табы, при клике, на ссылку таба задается другой  болдовый шрифт. Из-за этого блоки идущие за ним сдвигаются. Т.к. у первого размер меняется. 
Как избежать этого?

Отступы у табов сделаны

```css
.b-tab-nav__link {
  color: #161616;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 12px 0 16px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}
.b-tab-nav__item.active .b-tab-nav__link {
  font-feight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ffde00;
}
.b-tab-nav__item {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 49px;
}
```

```html
<ul role="tablist" class="b-tab-nav__list">
  <li role="presentation" class="active b-tab-nav__item"><a href="#recommended" aria-controls="recommended" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="Рекомендуем" class="b-tab-nav__link"><i class="icon-star"></i>Рекомендуем</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="b-tab-nav__item"><a href="#how-change" aria-controls="how-change" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="Как выбрать" class="b-tab-nav__link"><i class="icon-question-border"></i>Как выбрать</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="b-tab-nav__item"><a href="#video" aria-controls="video" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="Видео" class="b-tab-nav__link"><i class="icon-video"></i>Видео</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="b-tab-nav__item"><a href="#new" aria-controls="new" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="Обзоры новинок" class="b-tab-nav__link"><i class="icon-overview-new"></i>Обзоры новинок</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="b-tab-nav__item"><a href="#shopping-list" aria-controls="shopping-list" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="Списки покупок" class="b-tab-nav__link"><i class="icon-shopping-list"></i>Списки покупок</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jasvwkb3/1/

Comment: Пример вашего кода приведите.

Comment: @Moonvvell добавил. Правда без переключения табов.

Comment: "Правда без переключения табов" - чем меньше инфы по проблеме, тем меньше вероятность получить помощь

Comment: Задайте ширину табу и используйте `box-sizing: border-box;`. Других решений я не вижу.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы задала табам некую фиксированную ширину для начала.

Comment: Но без кода все же сложно понять, что уже сделано и как можно помочь в принципе.

Comment: Ширина хорошо, но не подходит, названия разные могут быть. Может манипуляции со шрифтами еще какие-нибудь провести можно. Добавил.

Answer (score 1):

Немного костыльное решение, зато без скриптов:

Отступы между табами делаете паддингами. Текст табов делаете невидимым.
Внутрь таба помимо уже невидимого текста вставляете такой же видимый, но с абсолютным позиционированием. Абсолютный текст и обычный невидимый должны накладываться друг на друга.

Зачем все это: Невидимый текст будет задавать размеры табу, абсолютный текст при активации таба будет становиться жирным, но не будет влиять на размеры. Отступы паддингами нужны, чтобы текст не выходил за границы таба.